# Is there another way to determine object in a image beside objectmarker?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using OpenCV for python. I want create a description file about positive image that seems like this

```
person01103-60-60.bmp 1 186 116 173 169
person01105-60-30.bmp 1 184 111 157 170
person01106-60-15.bmp 1 179 136 146 144
...
```

Most resource told using objectmarker, but since I use thousands image database, marking the object one by one would be quite challenging. is there other way that I can use? thank you.

Comment: if there was a way to find your desired objects in the images you wouldn't have to train another classifier...

Comment: sometimes it is easier to use a simple classifier (color/shape/features) and pre-classify all your images. Then just accept or reject all those images in some workflow. This makes sense if accepting/rejecting the images is faster than manual annotation.

Comment: afaik there is an application opencv_annotation that supports you in marking all the objects, but I didnt test it myself yet, so I can't help about it.